# Extracting image links using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to extract image links from GoT wiki page
The first two links work find but the second two give me a 404 error code. 
I'm trying to find out what I'm doing wrong.

I've tried different combinations to come up with the right link.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import urllib.request as request
import re
```

```
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php' + \
'?title=List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes&oldid=802553687'
```

```
r = requests.get(url)
html_contents = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_contents, 'html.parser')
```

```
# Find all a tags in the soup 
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    # While looping through the text if you find img in 'a' tag
    # Then print the src attribute
    if a.img: 
        print('http:/'+a.img['src'])
# And here are the images on the page
```

http:///upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/e/e7/Cscr-featured.svg/20px-Cscr-featured.svg.png

http:///upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2e/Game_of_Thrones_2011_logo.svg/300px-Game_of_Thrones_2011_logo.svg.png

http://static/images/wikimedia-button.png

http://static/images/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png

The first two links work

But I want to get the second two links to work as well.

Comment: these links give me 404 in web browser too. How did you get these links ? Maybe they need some headers in requests - ie. `Referer` or `User-Agent`.

Comment: urls are relative - you have to add `https://en.wikipedia.org/` at the beginning to get full URLs like `https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/wikimedia-button.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These urls starts with `/` so they are without domain and you have to add `https://en.wikipedia.org` to get full URLs like `https://en.wikipedia.org/static/images/wikimedia-button.png`

More or less:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes&oldid=802553687'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if a.img:
        src = a.img['src']
        if src.startswith('http'):
            print(src)
        elif src.startswith('//'):
            print('https:' + src)
        elif src.startswith('/'):
            print('https://en.wikipedia.org' + src)
        else:
            print('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/' + src)
```

---

**EDIT:** you can also use `urllib.parse.urljoin()`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes&oldid=802553687'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    if a.img:
        src = a.img['src']
        print(urllib.parse.urljoin('https://en.wikipedia.org', src))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help. I kept it simple. Here is what worked for me:

```
# Find all a tags in the soup 
for a in soup.find_all('a'):
    # While looping through the text if you find img in 'a' tag
    # Then print the src attribute
    if a.img:
        if a.img['src'][:2] == '//':
            print('https:'+a.img['src'])
        else:
            print('https://en.wikipedia.org/'+a.img['src'])
# And here are the images on the page
```